# Does Mietpreisbremse apply to furnished apartments?

Tags: germany, rental

I know there have already been some discussions on Mietpreisbremse and I've looked through them, however, the situation still seems confusing and different sources give different answers. Some people claim that the Mietpreisbremse doesn't apply to furnished apartments, while some others do.

I've read in several websites online that usually the landlord can charge 2% of the furniture monthly. However, the only basis for that claim seems to be a decision made in a Berlin court a long time ago.

I wonder if something has changed/been clarified since the law has apparently been prolonged for 5 more years just recently.

On ImmobilienScout24 the vast majority of rental listings I see (in Berlin, München etc.) seem to have double the price of what the Mietspiegel would suggest, even though they are not new buildings. It sounds barely plausible to reach such a price, even with a full set of luxury furniture (not to mention many apartments only have random IKEA-level furniture anyways). Maybe the Einbauküche and kitchen appliances costs some money but it's unlikely to be that much either.

I think the following paragraphs from this article last year https://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2019-11/moeblierte-wohnungen-vermietung-homelike-wunderflats-mietpreisbremse/komplettansicht summarized the situation quite well:

> Die große Koalition hatte im Jahr 2015 die Mietpreisbremse eingeführt. Sie sollte die extremen Steigerungen der Mietpreise begrenzen. Bei der Wiedervermietung einer Wohnung, die in einem angespannten Markt liegt, darf die Miete höchstens zehn Prozent über der ortsüblichen Vergleichsmiete liegen. Diese Regeln gelten auch für möblierte Wohnungen – das sehen zumindest die Mieterschützer so. Laut Rechtsprechung ist aber ein Aufschlag für die Möblierung erlaubt: Im Jahr 2003 hat das Landgericht Berlin diesen Zuschlag auf die Monatsmiete mit zwei Prozent des Zeitwerts der Möbel beziffert. Demnach dürfte eine Wohnung, die für 5.000 Euro möbliert wurde, monatlich um 100 Euro teurer sein als eine unmöblierte. Bisher ist das Urteil allerdings nur die Meinung eines einzelnen Gerichtes. Vom Bundesgerichtshof, der in diesem Fall zuständig wäre, wurde es nicht bestätigt.

> Wie problematisch das Zwei-Prozent-Urteil sein kann, zeigt sich, wenn man etwa beim anfangs erwähnten "wundervollen Zuhause" in Neukölln nachrechnet. Selbst wenn man eine ortsübliche Vergleichsmiete von zehn Euro pro Quadratmeter annimmt und Nebenkosten, Heizkosten und Strom miteinbezieht, kommt man auf eine zulässige Miete von 535 Euro für die 35 Quadratmeter. Bei einem Möblierungszuschlag von zwei Prozent des Zeitwerts der Möbel müsste die Einrichtung zwischen 35.000 und 40.000 Euro gekostet haben, um die 1.400 Euro Miete zu rechtfertigen – und komplett neu sein.

If this is true, then the so-called "2 percent rule" for furnished apartments seems to actually be some sort of legal gray zone, and each case will have to be decided separately?

I'm wondering about this since I just realized that the Kaltmiete for my furnished apartment (in a central area in Berlin, unlimited contract) is almost 300 Euros more than the Mietspiegel. However, it feels like the landlord mostly left some cheap furniture in there so as to make it "furnished". It's hard to justify this price if we apply the 2 percent rule.

But when I look at comparable online listings in similar locations, they are almost all *even more expensive* than what I'm currently paying. This makes me wonder if Mietpreisbremse is being invoked at all, or are most people just content with paying the higher price, since they feel this is just how the market is at the moment, and it's quite hard to find a place. I wonder if it's ever worth the trouble to complain about my rental contract after all. I don't intend to search for a new place in the short term.

I bought Rechtsschutzversicherung about 3 months ago, but clearly it doesn't cover the rental contract that I signed, which started 1 year ago. I was surprised to find out that the Prozesskostenrechtsschutz offered by Berliner Mieterverein https://www.berliner-mieterverein.de/beratung-und-service/prozesskostenrechtsschutz.htm also has a similar clause. It makes me wonder if there is a point in going to the Mieterverein, since I have to join them before I can make a consultation, but the membership in the Mieterverein has a minimum duration of 2 years... Though maybe most cases were resolved by the Mieterverein communicating with the landlord already, without them ever going to a Prozess?

Comment: Your question lacks a crucial point, without which no true answer can be given: Is the contract for a short term rent (up to 1 year, no automatic renewal) or a long term rent (a contract for 6 months, that is automatically renewed when not cancelled is a long term rent).  [Hürden für die Mietpreisbremse Teil 2 – Möbliert und auf Zeit | MINEKO.de](https://www.mineko.de/ausnahmen-mietpreisbremse-moeblierter-wohnraum/). For short term: no ; for long term :yes. You should really should go to a **Mieterverein**, where after looking at the *whole picture* can give you proper advice.

Comment: This question should be moved to **law.stackexchange.com**.